# Printing dates corresponding to last non-NA value in a subset of a dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to extract the dates (year) which correspond to the last available values (value) of a large panel dataset. Since my data needs to besubset I am using a do and group_by. The actual inner function that prints the last date has worked for me during a one-off try, but I can't get it to work in this looping framework.

I tried this:

```
last_observation <- mydf %>%
  group_by(indicator, country, version) %>%
  do({
    x <- which(!is.na(value))
    print(mydf$year[max(x)]) 
  })
```

But this yields the error: "Error: Results are not data frames at positions: (insert a bunch of positions here)".

Any suggestions? Sorry if this is too basic a question, I've only started learning R this week.

Edit: repruducible sample data added.

```
year <- c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013,2010, 2011, 2012,     
      2013, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2010, 2011, 2012,    
      2013, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013)
country <- c(rep("Australia", times =8), rep("Canada", times = 8), rep("Australia", times =8), rep("Canada", times = 8))
indicator <- c(rep("Apples", times = 16), rep("Bananas", times = 16))
versiondata <- c(rep("new", times = 4), rep("old", times = 4), rep("new", times = 4), rep("old", times = 4), rep("new", times = 4), rep("old", times = 4), rep("new", times = 4), rep("old", times = 4))
value <- c(runif(3), "NA", runif(2), "NA", "NA", runif(23), "NA")
mydf <- data.frame(year, country, indicator, versiondata, value)
```

Ideally, what I would need from this sample df is a vector as follows:

```
c(2012,2011,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012)
```

I.e, for each group (by country, indicator and versiondata) the date of thelast available value. I hope I could express myself well enough.

Comment: provide a reproducible example

Comment: @Ilya Kashnitsky I added a reproducible sample dataframe